# Conversion from different types

Tags: coq

```
 Inductive color: Type :=
 | red 
 | green
 | blue.
Inductive listw : Type :=
  | nil : listw
  | cons : web -> listw -> listw.
Definition colorlist (c:color) : listw :=
  match w with 
  | red => (cons red nil)
  | green => (cons green nil)
  | blue => (cons blue nil)
end.
Notation "x ++ y" := (app x y)
                     (right associativity, at level 60).
Definition bag:=listw.
Definition bag:=((cons red nil)++(cons green nil)++(cons blue nil)).
Bag = cons red (cons green (cons blue nil)).
```

I have defined  list of colors ( inductive type ). Want to replace each color with specific natural number. I have problem in assigning natural number to different inductive type list.

Comment: Why are you redefining lists? Is it for an assignment? What is it exactly that you want? Associating say `red` with `1`, `green` with `2` and `blue` with `3` and then replace all of them in a list? `List.map` would do the trick I suppose.

Comment: I am assigning natural number, because I have function that counts occurrence of natural numbers in a list and sort them. In this way I will be able to use my already defined function.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hard time figuring out what you want exactly, so I will try to write an answer for what I make out.

You have a type of colours:

```
Inductive color := 
| red
| green
| blue.
```

Then you want to get a list of natural numbers from it. So you associate a number to each colour:

```
Definition nat_of_color (c : color) : nat :=
  match c with
  | red => 0
  | green => 1
  | blue => 2
  end.
```

Now, if you were to use the `list` type provided by coq, the function you want is:

```
Definition nat_list_of_color_list (l : list color) : list nat :=
  List.map nat_of_color l.
```

In other words, `List.map nat_of_color` is the function you seem to wish for.

Note that the sorting algorithm and occurence count can probably be made more generic to work with colours right off the bat.

Comment: Thank you for help.I am really looking for this function.

Comment: Are you wondering how `List.map` is defined now? Or have I answered your question? In the latter case, it is customary to mark the answer as accepted so it might help other people with similar concerns.

Comment: I am looking in the standard library for map function, but the List.map(with this name ) no function exist. Therefore I want to know about its detail. If you explain, thank you for it

Comment: Three to four time you have guide me about the use of such functions To reply about the usefulness of your answer, I always increase the number to the left of answer.(option :how useful this answer is but I get answer )         “Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.”. Therefore unable to give feedback.  I am on mistake ,please correct me.

Comment: I want to learn about such functions, therefore I started reading standard library. Is this is enough? You can give reference to some material?

Comment: You can also click on the tick to the left of an answer to say it has solved your problem. Regarding `List.map`, it is a usual construct in functional programming languages, the module `List` of coq if there: https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html.